# Thread in driver don't send packets

Tags: multithreading, filter, driver, packet, ndis

I have [this NDIS Filter Driver](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/NDISLWFSYS-Sample-NDIS-60-42b76875). I try to start in my driver a thread, that will send packet every 10 seconds.

To do that, I use this code:

```
LARGE_INTEGER TimePrev, TimeNow;
void ThreadedAction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        KeQuerySystemTime(&TimeNow);
        if(NBLtoSend && (TimeNow.QuadPart - TimePrev.QuadPart)>100000000)
        {
            NdisFSendNetBufferLists(NBLtoSend->SourceHandle, NBLtoSend, 0, 0);
            KeQuerySystemTime(&TimePrev);
        }
    }
}
```

The function started with `PsCreateSystemThread` in `DriverEntry`.
**But this is not sends my packet.**
I try to use this:

```
void ThreadedAction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(NBLtoSend)
        {
            NdisFSendNetBufferLists(NBLtoSend->SourceHandle, NBLtoSend, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

This code sends my packet non stop.

The following code creates new file with my packet every 10 seconds(CreateFileS is my function), **but don't sends my packet**:

```
LARGE_INTEGER TimePrev, TimeNow;
void ThreadedAction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        KeQuerySystemTime(&TimeNow);
        if(NBLtoSend && (TimeNow.QuadPart - TimePrev.QuadPart)>100000000)
        {
            PMDL pmdl = NET_BUFFER_CURRENT_MDL(NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(NBLtoSend));
            CreateFileS(NULL,(char*)MmGetMdlVirtualAddress(pmdl),MmGetMdlByteCount(pmdl));
            NdisFSendNetBufferLists(NBLtoSend->SourceHandle, NBLtoSend, 0, 0);
            KeQuerySystemTime(&TimePrev);
        }
    }
}
```

Why it's happened, and what can I do to send packet every 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The NDIS6 programming model is asynchronous.  This means when you call `NdisFSendNetBufferLists`, you actually give up ownership of the NBL.  You cannot reuse the NBL until it is returned to your filter via your [FilterReturnNetBufferLists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549964%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) callback.

So first off, you need to change the code to look more like this:

```
PNET_BUFFER_LIST NblToSend;

void FilterReturnNetBufferLists(PNET_BUFFER_LIST NblChain)
{
    for each Nbl in NblChain
    {
        if(Nbl->SourceHandle == MyFilterHandle)
            NblToSend = Nbl;
        else
            NdisFReturnNetBufferLists(Nbl);
    }
}

void ThreadedAction()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(NBLtoSend)
        {
            PNET_BUFFER_LIST TempNbl = NblToSend;
            NblToSend = NULL;
            NdisFSendNetBufferLists(TempNbl);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you honor the NDIS rule: Do not send an NBL again until it's been returned to you.

Next up, the looping is highly inefficient.  As implemented, the loop will consume 100% of the CPU, busily counting down the nanoseconds until it's time to send another packet.  Instead, [use a timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The system will call into your thread when 10 seconds have elapsed.

Comment: **1.** Are you sure it's `FilterReturnNetBufferLists` and not `FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete`?  
**2.** If the problem occurs because I pass the ownership of the NBL to NDIS, why it's doesn't sends in the first call?, and why it's sends the packet when I don't check the time?  
**3.** I don't use timer, because this thread do also something else, which I want to execute all the time.

Comment: 1.  Yes, silly me.  I meant `FilerSendNetBufferListsComplete`

Comment: 2.  I'm not sure what this question means; could you rephrase?

Comment: you said that my code cannot send the packet, because "You cannot **reuse** the NBL until it is returned to your filter via your FilterReturnNetBufferLists callback". in the first time the code is executed, I am don't reuse the NBL, and don't gave up ownership of the NBL. then why the packet doesn't sent in the first time?

Comment: When you call `NdisFSendNetBufferLists`, that gives up ownership of the NBL.  You cannot touch the NBL again until it comes back to you via `FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete`.